# How do I override mounts of the devcontainer.json config for local users with settings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I want users of different platforms to be able to seamlessly launch my project and get the right mounts setup.

Here is an example of some mounts that *might* vary on different platforms (even though I'm using `${localEnv:HOME}`.

```
"mounts": [
    "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.aws/credentials,target=/root/.aws/credentials,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.config/gcloud,target=/root/.config/gcloud,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.config/pip,target=/root/.config/pip,type=bind,consistency=cached",
```

I want to keep the default mounts hard coded in `devcontainer.json` which is committed to source because these settings work for 80% of my users. But how can users override the mounts in a non committed config file?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but I'm looking for this exact capability.  I found a feature request for the spec, https://github.com/devcontainers/spec/issues/22.  Looks like it may not be possible currently.