# Is it possible to define system level environment variables in a local settings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

This is not for launch configurations, these env vars would need to be injected as system env vars when vscode starts.

I want to let users override dev container volume mounts. This has been an open feature request for years: [How do I override mounts of the devcontainer.json config for local users with settings.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002240/how-do-i-override-mounts-of-the-devcontainer-json-config-for-local-users-with-se)

I'm trying to find a workaround and one possible way could be runargs with system level environment variables for example:

```
"runArgs": [
    "--volume=${env:SOME_ENV_VAR}:/tmp/derps:rw"
],
```

I can request users set a bunch of system level env vars, but that's annoying and wonky. I'd rather just provide an example: `.vscode/settings.json` or `.code-workspace` or user `setting.json` and say "set these env vars in your local vscode settings".

Can VS Code export system level env vars on startup that would be accessible from `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`?

Comment: see my answer to the linked dup-target. answer is no. and your question is weird. a process' environment variables don't have any distinction of whether they are "system" environment variables or not.